# Grep (a.txt - En word list, b.txt - one string in each line) Q: string from b.txt built only from words or not?

Tags: string, bash, grep

I have a list with English words (1 in each line, around 100.000)-> a.txt and a b.txt contains strings (around 50.000 line, one string in each line, can contain pure words, word+something, garbage). I would like to know which strings from b.txt contains English words only (without any additional chars).

Can I do this with `grep`?

Example:

`a.txt`:

```
apple
pie
```

`b.txt`:

```
applepie
applebs
bspie
bsabcbs
```

Output:

`c.txt`:

```
applepie
```

Comment: Be more verbose.  Currently, a solution to your question would be `echo "applepie" > c.txt`.  That's probably not what you want.  We don't like to guess or give answer into the blue.

Comment: The short answer is no, that's not possible with just `grep`. You need to manually match each possible permutation based on `a.txt` against `b.txt`.

Comment: Your edit has made this an even more complex endeavor. Not every permutation of words in `a.txt` will be a valid English compound word so what you are asking for wouldn't even solve your problem (based on your example your wordlist doesn't contain compound words). Even if you were to do this you would need to build a list of permutations which, given the size of your file, needs a sophisticated form of representation otherwise you will run into memory problems (some sort of tree). This is not something you want to solve with shell scripting. There really is no simple answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is underspecified, maybe this answer can help as a shot in the dark to clarify your question:

```
c='cat b.txt'
while IFS='' read -e line
do
  c="$c | grep '$line'"
done < a.txt
eval "$c" > c.txt
```

But this would also match a line like `this is my apply on a pie`.  I don't know if that's what you want.

This is another try:

```
re=''
while IFS='' read -e line
do
  re="$re${re:+|}$line"
done < a.txt
grep -E "^($re)*$" b.txt > c.txt
```

This will let pass only the lines which have nothing but a concatenation of these words.  But it will also let pass things like 'appleapplepieapplepiepieapple'.  Again, I don't know if this is what you want.

Given your latest explanation in the question I would propose another approach (because building such a list out of 100000+ words is not going to work).

A working approach for this amount of words could be to *remove* all recognized words from the text and see which lines get emptied in the process.  This can easily be done iteratively without exploding the memory usage or other resources.  It will take time, though.

```
cp b.txt inprogress.txt
while IFS='' read -e line
do
  sed -i "s/$line//g" inprogress.txt
done < a.txt
for lineNumber in $(grep -n '^$' inprogress.txt | sed 's/://')
do
  sed -n "${lineNumber}p" b.txt
done
rm inprogress.txt
```

But this still would not really solve your issue; consider if you have the words `to` and `potato` in your list, and removing the `to` would occur first, then this would leave a word `pota` in your text file, and `pota` is not a word which would then be removed.

You could address that issue by sorting your word file by word length (longest words first) but that still would be problematic in some cases of compound words, e. g. `redart` (being `red` + `art`) but `dart` would be removed first, so `re` would remain.  If that is not in your word list, you would not recognize this word.

Actually, your problem is one of logical programming and natural language processing and probably does not fit to SO.  You should have a look at the language *Prolog* which is designed around such problems as yours.

Comment: I still think this is not easily solvable; apparently OP's word list does not contain compound words so it's impossible to build a list of valid compound words to match the other file against.

Comment: You are absolutely right, 100000 words in this list blasts a lot of approaches.  But maybe something close to a solution is enough for OP.  Otherwise he should use sth different than just `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

I will post this as an answer as well since I feel this is the correct answer to your specific question.

Your requirement is to find non-English words in a file (`b.txt`) based on a word list ( `a.txt`) which contains a list of English words. Based on the example in your question said word list does not contain compound words (e.g. `applepie`) but you would still like to match the file against compound words based on words in your word list (e.g. `apple` and `pie`).

There are two problem you are facing:

1. Not every permutation of words in `a.txt` will be a valid English compound word so just based on this your problem is already impossible to solve.
2. If you, nonetheless, were to attempt building a list of compound words yourself by compiling a list of all possible permutations you cannot easily do this because of the size of your wordlist (and resulting memory problems). You would most probably have to store your words in a more complex data structure, e.g. a tree, and build permutations on the fly by traversing the tree which is not doable in shell scripting.

Because of these points and your actual question being "can this be done with `grep`?" the answer is no, this is not possible.